# .htaccess rewrite url to arguments

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?product=$1&price=$2
```

This code makes

> `http://www.example.com/products/computer/1000`

into

> `http://www.example.com/index.php?product=computer&price=1000`.

Is it possible to make

> `http://www.example.com/scriptName/arg1/val1/arg2/val2/arg3/val3`

into

> `http://www.example.com/scriptName.php?arg1=val1&arg2=val2&arg3=val3?`

The user should be able to give an unlimited number of arguments. This way one can have `/index.php?page=forum&subforum=subforum&quote1=postNo1&quote2=postNo43` and so on rewrite `/index/page/forum/subforum/subforum/quote1/postNo1/quote2/postNo43`

How would the `.htaccess` code look?

Comment: Your explanation is wrong.  E.g. your first example does an *internal redirect* to index.php with s query string `product=computer&price=1000`.  You can't use `.htaccess` as you wish, but why bother?  Just parse the *path_info* or if you don't want to change the code use a autoload script to do this.

Comment: @TerryE Yes, I know it is internal. Do you mean to make a .php file to do it for me?

Comment: Yup, look up the PHP docn on **auto_prepend_file**.  You can just parse path_info and overwrite $_GET ... for the invoked script to pick up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*?)/?$ $1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

This will forward a URI of `/scriptName/arg1/val1/arg2/val2/arg3/val3` to `/scriptName.php?arg3=val3&arg2=val2&arg1=val1`

Comment: Says who? :) This is a recursion based rule and it will work with any number of args, (as long as they are balanced in pairs). I have tested this with upto 7 args.